# pd.read_excel not able to read a xlsx file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, jupyter-notebook, xlsx

I am trying to read an xlsx file using pd.read_excel but getting an error like this:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0Qz0.png)

My code snippet looks like this:
[Notebook code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSkoy.png)

When i tried to open the xlsx file directly from notebook i got this error:
[opening xlsx file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sa8il.png)

PLease help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title says `pd.read_excel`, but your code says `pd.read_csv`.  CSV files are plain text files, readable with Notepad.  XLSX files are binary, and are not human-readable.  If you have an XLSX file, then use `pd.read_excel`, like your title says.

Comment: Don't judge me lol, thanks for responsive environment here.